# What is the correct way to set the session duration for continuing it in PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Usually a site offers to the user the choice to remember his login, so it will set the cookie lifetime to zero or X the first time session starts.

To remember this choice I put the lifetime value inside the $_SESSION var. But when I want to continue the session, I can't retrieve this value *before* the session is started, and if I want to call session_set_cookie_params() I must do it before.

So currently I do *not* call session_set_cookie_params() when I continue a session. On the contrary I store the current time when the session start and check it when the session continue. This is the code (note: **it's a simplified version**, the original code has all the other needed stuff, as session_register_shutdown()):

```
// when I start the session

[...]

session_set_cookie_params($duration); // $duration was set before
session_start();      
$_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
$_SESSION['duration'] = $duration;


//-----------------------------------
// when I continue the session


$ok = true;

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['starttime']))
{
    $elapsed = $_SESSION['starttime']; - time();
    $duration = $_SESSION['duration'];
    if ($elapsed >= $duration and $duration !== 0)
    {
        $ok = false;
    }
}
else
{
    $ok = false;
}

if (! $ok)
{
    // destroy the session
}
```

Is this correct? If not, why and is there a smarter way to handle the session duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the cookie lifetime is not the only thing you have to do, you will also have to set `session.max_lifetime` – which is named incorrectly, and is actually a *min* lifetime, that has to pass after last access to the session file, before the garbage collector is allowed to clean it from disk.

You should probably not use the session mechanism itself for this at all. Instead, set a cookie of your own, that allows you to recognize a logged in user again – f.e. containing username or id, and the something unique to the user hashed with a secret salt. If you receive that cookie value (and have verified it) and don’t have a logged in user in your session already – log them in, load all necessary data to put into the session, etc.

Comment: Well, this does not answer to the "why" :) Why should I not use the session mechanism?

Comment: Because :-) First of all because of the session file lifetime you will have to increase (a lot) – so a lot more session files than usual will accumulate. And then there will be a lot of data in those files (probably?), most of which you don’t need stored there while the user is not active on your page.

Comment: You're right, I never thought about this, but can't I modify the behavior of the garbage collector to not remove the session but only the session data, apart lifetime and starttime? I'm asking this because storing the db id inside the cookie, even if crypted, seems to me insecure.

Comment: Sessions work the following way: The client sends the session id with every request, and the server looks if he finds a session file with corresponding name (if so, he picks up that session again), or he creates a new session file. What the GC is, is to simple remove that session file - so you can not keep the session without the session file.

Comment: As for storing any kind of user id, hashed together with whatever being insecure - not much more insecure as sessions themselves, because both use a “random” looking key that not outsider can guess. Problematic would only be cookie stealing - but that could be countered by creating a new hash with a random salt every time the user visit the site, and saving that new salt into the DB as well.

Comment: Well, yes, but session ids can be completely changed, while if you decrypt the db id you'll have it forever. It's like storing the encrypted password inside the cookie.